# pecl install gnupg on win8

Tags: windows, pecl

Can`t install pnupg extension for win8: php 5.4 (x86).

i had installed this http://files.gpg4win.org/gpg4win-2.2.1.exe
Than tried to install php extension:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerCmd>pecl install gnupg
downloading gnupg-1.3.3.tgz ...
Starting to download gnupg-1.3.3.tgz (19,141 bytes)
......done: 19,141 bytes
5 source files, building
WARNING: php_bin c:\php_5_4\php.exe appears to have a suffix _5_4\php.exe, but config variable php_suffix does not match
ERROR: The DSP gnupg.dsp does not exist.
```

tied to fix this with:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerCmd>pecl config-set php_suffix .exe
config-set succeeded
```

does not helps:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerCmd>pecl install gnupg
downloading gnupg-1.3.3.tgz ...
Starting to download gnupg-1.3.3.tgz (19,141 bytes)
......done: 19,141 bytes
5 source files, building
WARNING: php_bin c:\php_5_4\php.exe appears to have a suffix _5_4\php.exe, but config variable php_suffix does not match
ERROR: The DSP gnupg.dsp does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run this command and install again:

```
pecl config-set php_suffix "-cgi.exe"
```